# Save UIImage to PNG in App Bundle in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiimage, uiimagepngrepresentation

With the new iOS 10.3 beta I heard that you can change the icon of your app programmatically using a PNG file included in your app and mentioning it in your `Info.plist`. I have successfully done this using images that were already in my app at build-time. My idea was that you could set the image to whatever you want, by getting a PNG representation of a UIImage and then saving it to a PNG file inside your app bundle, so that when the icon is changed it will be changed to that UIImage.

Let's say I have a PNG file (`ic_custom.png`) in my app here:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGsYm.jpg

How would I save a UIImage to this exact file (so that Info.plist could still read it), and could I access it using the `setAlternateIcon` method **in Swift 3**? If you can't write to it, then is there a way that the Info.plist could still access it if it were in the Documents directory?

Comment: You can't modify your Bundle files

Comment: @LeoDabus Is there a way to link the Info.plist to the documents directory somehow?

Comment: I expect Apple does not want apps to be able to do what you want. The icon images have to be pre-defined - and reviewable by Apple. It looks like the Major League Baseball app has used this to allow customers to change the app icon to the logo of their favorite team.